# How can I parse just date from datetime string in MVC VIEW

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

View in MVC

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <div>
   @item.CreatedOn
  </div>
 }
```

this content is displayed
3/4/2015 2:12:19 PM

I want to display this
2:12 PM

Comment: So do you want to display it like 3/4/2015 2:12 PM? or Only  2:12 PM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your `CreatedOn` is `DateTime` type you can use `ToShortTimeString()` method ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring(v=vs.110).aspx)) like this:

```
@item.CreatedOn.ToShortTimeString()
```

else you should convert value

```
@Convert.ToDateTime(item.CreatedOn).ToShortTimeString()
```

Comment: @Convert.ToDateTime(item.CreatedOn).ToShortTimeString() worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

MDSN has a list of all the [Standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Custom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Date and Time formats, which the [DateTime ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function recognizes.

The display you want is the standard format "t". So you can simply change it to:

```
@item.CreatedOn.ToString("t")
```